# Difference in bandwidth for scikit-learn KDE and multivariate KDE of statsmodels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels, bandwidth, kernel-density

I am generating a 5000 * 6 array and using KDE from scikit-learn and MultivariateKDE from statsmodel to evaluate ln(probability density). Since, both can handle multi-dimensional data, I hoped that I would get the same result using both method. But, the results are different. When I looked into the value of bandwidth, I saw scikit-learn KDE uses a scalar value for bandwidth and Multivariate KDE uses a 1D array for bandwidth.

So, **which bandwidth is correct ?**

I am attaching the code snippet below,

```
# Generating random data
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
X = rng.random_sample((5000,6))

# Using Grid search to get the best bandwidth
params = {'bandwidth': np.logspace(-1, 1, 20)}
grid = GridSearchCV(KernelDensity(), params)
grid.fit(X)
print("best bandwidth for scikit-learn: {0}".format(grid.best_estimator_.bandwidth))

# Using scikit-learn kde
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=grid.best_estimator_.bandwidth).fit(X)
log_density = kde.score_samples(X)

# Using Multivariate KDE from statsmodels
kde = sm.nonparametric.KDEMultivariate(data=X, var_type='cccccc', bw='normal_reference')
log_density_stat = np.log(kde.pdf(X))
print("best bandwidth for statsmodels : ", kde.bw)
```

The corresponding output is as follows,

```
best bandwidth for scikit-learn: 0.1
best bandwidth for statsmodels :  [0.12904    0.13105721 0.12936657 0.13071426 0.13008811 0.13102085]
```

Comment: you have asked a fairly  specialised niche question and had no answer this far. You have actually asked two questions. Perhaps you could try to break your question up and ask an initial question which followers of the tags could easily answer. Maybe sort out the difference between the bandwidth parameters first and then explore which model fits your data best as a separate thing.

Comment: Okay, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct" bandwidth *per se*, you just obtained two bandwidth values from two different methods, the first one looking for a unique value (using a univariate grid search), and the second one looking for several values, it would seem estimated using [Scott's rule of thumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_kernel_density_estimation#Rule_of_thumb), as shown in the [`_normal_reference` method of `GenericKDE`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/nonparametric/_kernel_base.html).

The values of the bandwidth correspond to the diagonal of the bandwidth matrix: they are all equal with scikit-learn's estimation, and can be different with statsmodels's estimation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Just one quick question --- when dealing with multidimensional data (dimension >= 5), which method is more preferred - KDE from scikit-learn or Multivariate KDE from statsmodels ?

Comment: I would favor statsmodels' KDE, since it handles different values in the diagonal of the covariance matrix, wheras scikit-learn allows for only one unique value. 

However, given that in your example the values of bandwidth estimated by statsmodels are quite close to each other, you might obtain results as good with scikit-learn and a unique bandwidth of 0.13.

If, with other data, you have standard deviations that vary a lot from one dimension to another, then I would definitely use statsmodels' KDE, since the estimated bandwidth would also vary greatly from one dimension to another.